# Can biscuit dough be left out at room temperature before baking?

Tags: baking, biscuits

I have an event I've volunteered to bring biscuits to. I'm making kimchi cheddar biscuits (baking powder, baking soda, buttermilk are the leavening ingredients I believe). The recipe says to freeze the biscuit dough for an hour before baking.

I can either:

-follow the recipe: freezing my dough for an hour, cooking and allowing the biscuits to cool completely before bringing them to my event, which I will then be very late to

-bring the fully assembled uncooked biscuit dough TO the event, arriving on time, and using my friend's kitchen to freeze+bake there.

Are there any downsides to packing finished biscuit dough into a few tupperwares and letting it rest for an hour or so as I bus over to my event? I'd be as conscious as I could be about over-handling it.

Answer (score 18):

The [purpose of freezing biscuits](https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/blog/2018/05/21/bake-best-biscuits) before baking is to make sure that the layers of fat are nice and hard, and don't have a chance to soak into the flour before they start steaming and pushing the layers apart.  If your dough is sitting for an hour or more at room temperature (or warmer), you risk them being doughy and/or tough and not rising properly.

Freezing them solid (6+ hours), carrying them in a cooler, and then [baking them from frozen](https://www.thepioneerwoman.com/food-cooking/cooking-tips-tutorials/a88328/how-to-freeze-biscuits/) on-site should work, though.  The key there is not letting them start thawing before they go into the oven -- half-thawed but frozen in the middle would be even worse that starting them at room temp.

Answer (score 3):

It’s really difficult to know.

Depending on the thickness of the biscuit and your freezer temperature, the one hour freeze might be to chill the outside to change how it bakes.

My first thought was to freeze the biscuits hard, then carry in an insulated container with an ice pack, but that might create the opposite effect—- a frozen middle and a slightly thawed exterior, so the biscuit browns faster but is still doughy in the middle.

I suspect by the question that it’s probably too late to suggest mixing all of the dry components together, then heading over early to make them there.  Especially at most events, oven time is at a premium, so it might not even be available.

So my second thought would be to bake them at home, then re-warm them on site, but you said you didn’t have time for that.

If you are going to go this route, As you’re short on time, I would wrap the biscuits in a clean dish towel as soon as you can get them off the sheet pan.  This will help to absorb any steam them give off and reduce the chance of condensation messing up the crust.  It also helps to insulate them to keep them warm for the trip.